# Prevent changing of shipping method at Paypal Review page

Tags: shipping, paypal, magento-1.6

I would like to know how to prevent `shipping method change` at order `review page` (https://www.mysite.com/paypal/express/review/).

I am using `Magento 1.6.0` and Paypal `Express Checkout`.

Comment: This is the review page that comes after paypal page is visited by user..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this:

## Suppress in the view file

Copy **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/review/shipping/method.phtml** to your package/theme, and change the contents to:

```
<fieldset id="shipping-method-container">
    <p><strong><?php echo $this->renderShippingRateOption($this->getCurrentShippingRate())?></strong></p>
</fieldset>
<div style="display:none" id="shipping_method_update"><p><?php echo $this->__('Please update order data to get shipping methods and rates') ?></p></div>
```

---

## Set the option within the Model

Perform a model rewrite in your local module of **app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php** and rewrite only this following method:

```
/**
 * Check whether order review has enough data to initialize
 *
 * @param $token
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 */
public function prepareOrderReview($token = null)
{
    parent::prepareOrderReview($token);
    $this->_quote->setMayEditShippingMethod(false);
    $this->_ignoreAddressValidation();
    $this->_quote->collectTotals()->save();
}
```

Comment: The first idea doesnt work as I dont have `"shipping/method.phtml"`... Thats because this is the review page that comes after paypal page is visited by user..

Comment: but the 2nd idea was fantastic... thanks..