# Rewrite model to prevent changing shipping method at review order stage of checkout

Tags: checkout, overrides, paypal, model, magento-1.9.2.0

I'm trying to override a model class to prevent customers changing the shipping address and method at the (final) order review stage of checkout, using [this suggestion](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4698/prevent-changing-of-shipping-method-at-paypal-review-page). This is the point at which the customer has been returned from PayPal in order to check over the order before finally clicking the 'Place Order' button. We pre-agree shipping costs with our customers via a quotation so giving them the option to change shipping method doesn't make any sense.

This is my first attempt at doing this in Magento. It feels like I'm *nearly* there but it's not working:

[image: Review Order Shipping Method is still editable]

If anyone with experience of overriding model classes in Magento could tell me where I'm going wrong that would be fantastic.

(1)
(a) Create /app/code/local/Lms/Paypal/Model/Express and copy in /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php

(b) Rename class in Checkout.php from: Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout 
to: Lms_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout extends Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout

(c) Clear out the class body and replace with just this function:

```
/**
 * Check whether order review has enough data to initialize
 *
 * @param $token
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 */
public function prepareOrderReview($token = null)
{
    parent::prepareOrderReview($token);
    $this->_quote->setMayEditShippingAddress(false);
    $this->_quote->setMayEditShippingMethod(false);
    $this->_ignoreAddressValidation();
    $this->_quote->collectTotals()->save();
}
```

(2)
(a) Now create dir /app/code/local/Lms/Paypal/etc/
(b) Create Config.xml file in that dir and put this code there:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <lms_paypal>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </lms_paypal>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <paypal>
              <rewrite>
                  <express>Lms_Paypal_Model_Express</express>
              </rewrite>
          </paypal>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

(3)
(a) Now go to /app/etc/modules/
(b) Create Lms_Paypal.xml in that dir and put this code in Lms_Paypal.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<config>  
    <modules>  
        <Lms_Paypal>  
            <active>true</active>  
            <codePool>local</codePool>  
        </Lms_Paypal>  
    </modules>  
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going wrong way in `/app/code/local/Lms/Paypal/etc/config.xml` and model file

```
/app/code/local/Lms/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
```

Replace `config.xml` file code from

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <lms_paypal>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </lms_paypal>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <paypal>
              <rewrite>
                  <express>Lms_Paypal_Model_Express</express>
              </rewrite>
          </paypal>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**To**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lms_Paypal>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Lms_Paypal>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <paypal>
              <rewrite>
                  <express_checkout>Lms_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout</express_checkout>
              </rewrite>
          </paypal>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Also replace code in file `app/code/local/Lms/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php` from

```
public function prepareOrderReview($token = null)
{
    parent::prepareOrderReview($token);
    $this->_quote->setMayEditShippingAddress(false);
    $this->_quote->setMayEditShippingMethod(false);
    $this->_ignoreAddressValidation();
    $this->_quote->collectTotals()->save();
}
```

**To**

```
class Lms_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout extends Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout
{

    public function prepareOrderReview($token = null)
    {
        $payment = $this->_quote->getPayment();
        if (!$payment || !$payment->getAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_PAYER_ID)) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Payer is not identified.'));
        }
        $this->_quote->setMayEditShippingAddress(false);
        $this->_quote->setMayEditShippingMethod(false);
        $this->_ignoreAddressValidation();
        $this->_quote->collectTotals()->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Abdul, thanks very much for your suggestion. I made these changes but unfortunately it's still not working.

Comment: updated ans pls check and also remove magento Cache  in admin side.

Comment: Hi Abdul, thanks, tried again but still no luck. This time I'm getting a fatal error though so maybe some progress. Calling '<base_url>/paypal/express/start/' I get: 
'Fatal error: Call to a member function setCustomerWithAddressChange() on a non-object in <path_to_root>/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php on line 72'